# How to access elements of a matrix based on values of a vector

Tags: matlab

So say I have the below matrix

```
[1, 2, 3,
4, 5, 6,
7, 8, 9]
```

And I have a vector [1,3]

I want to access the 1st and 3rd row which would return

```
[1,2,3
7,8,9]
```

I need to be able to scale this up to about 1000 rows being grabbed based on values in the vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if `A` is your matrix and `v` your vector of index, you just have to do `A(v,:)`